# down-mouse-1: Messages only visible for a split second

Tags: mouse, echo-area

In the following example, the `down-mouse-1` key is bound to `test-func`.  The message `Hello-world!` is only visible in the echo area for a split-second.  **Q**:  How can a user prevent the message from immediately disappearing in the echo area?

```lisp
(defun test-func (event)
  (interactive "e")
  (message "Hello-world!"))

(global-set-key [down-mouse-1] 'test-func)
(global-set-key [mouse-1] 'ignore)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the message on the up event, `mouse-1`, instead of on the down event, `down-mouse-1`:

```lisp
(global-set-key [down-mouse-1] 'ignore)
(global-set-key [mouse-1] 'test-func)
```